# Calculation on array objects having same property values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array as-

```
const a = [
  {
    value: 1,
    week: 'week1',
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    week: 'week1',
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    week: 'week16',
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    week: 'week0',
  },
  {
    value: 5,
    week: 'week16',
  },
]
```

I want to have a modified array in the following way-

```
let modified = [
  {
    value: 1.5,
    week: 'week1',
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    week: 'week16',
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    week: 'week0',
  },
]
```

In this modified array, the duplicate week has been put only once and the value has been replaced by average of total value in the particular duplicate objects.

Comment: Have you tried any solution or put any effort to find the logic to fix your problem. If yes then its better to put your findings.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the values in an object, and then calculate the average by dividing their sum over the number of available values for a given week:

```js
const a = [{
  value: 1,
  week: 'week1',
}, {
  value: 2,
  week: 'week1',
}, {
  value: 3,
  week: 'week16',
}, {
  value: 4,
  week: 'week0',
}, {
  value: 5,
  week: 'week16',
}];

const result = Object.entries(
  a.reduce((a, {value, week}) => ({
    ...a,
    [week]: [...a[week] || [], value]
  }), {})
).map(([week, values]) => ({
  week,
  value: values.reduce((a, v) => a + v, 0) / values.length
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in simple way like below,

1.Create a map and added values of similar week and kept their count
2.Then created modified from that.

```
const a = [
    {
        value: 1,
        week: 'week1',
    },
    {
        value: 2,
        week: 'week1',
    },
    {
        value: 3,
        week: 'week16',
    },
    {
        value: 4,
        week: 'week0',
    },
    {
        value: 5,
        week: 'week16',
    },
];


const helperMap = {}

a.forEach((obj) => {
    if (!!helperMap[obj.week]) {
        helperMap[obj.week]['sum'] += obj.value;
        helperMap[obj.week]['count'] += 1;
    } else {
        helperMap[obj.week] = { sum: obj.value, count: 1 };
    }
});

const modified = [];
for (let week in helperMap) {
    let avgValue = helperMap[week]['sum'] / helperMap[week]['count'];
    modified.push({ week, value: avgValue });
}

console.log(modified)
```

We can do it in short forms using inbuilt functions also, but it will be better to understand the concept

Answer (score -1):

```js
const a = [
    {
        value: 1,
        week: 'week1',
    },
    {
        value: 2,
        week: 'week1',
    },
    {
        value: 3,
        week: 'week16',
    },
    {
        value: 4,
        week: 'week0',
    },
    {
        value: 5,
        week: 'week16',
    },
]

let modified = [];
a.forEach(item => {
    let match = modified.find(m => m.week === item.week);
    if (match) match.value = (match.value + item.value);
    else modified.push(item);
});
modified.forEach(m => m.value =  m.value / a.filter(a => a.week === m.week).length);
console.log(modified)
```

Comment: Using this logic, the average of 2, 2 and 8 will be 5, while it's actually 4.